# error connecting to MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, connection

Here is the config.php file

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

/*=========== Database Configuraiton ==========*/

$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "test";
$db_pass = "test";
$db_name = "dbtest";


/*=========== Website Configuration ==========*/

$defaultTitle = 'testing';
$defaultFooter = date('Y').' &copy; testing';

?>
```

Here is the reference to config.php

```
<?php


require_once "includes/config.php";
require_once "includes/connect.php";
require_once "includes/helpers.php";



header('Cache-Control: max-age=3600, public');
header('Pragma: cache');
header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s",time())." GMT");
header("Expires: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s",time()+3600)." GMT");

?>
```

Connect.php is below

```
<?php

/*
        The login details are taken from config.php.
*/

try {
    $db = new PDO(
        "mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;charset=UTF-8",
        $db_user,
        $db_pass
    );

    $db->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    error_log($e->getMessage());
    die("A database error was encountered");
}


?>
```

Does anyone see the problem with this code?  I am getting the error message from connect.php "a database error was encountered"  I need another set of eyes because all my info looks correct and I can't see the error in the code.  Thanks.

Comment: You're writing the actual error to the error log, so what is the error message logged?

Comment: its saying call to undefined function

Comment: <?php

header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
render('_header',array('title'=>'Error'))

?>

<p><?php echo $message?></p>

<?php render('_footer')?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once try with your credentials directly instead of using them as variable.

also try to debug using below:

```
catch(PDOException $e) {
    error_log($e->getMessage());
    die("A database error was encountered -> " . $e->getMessage() );
}
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2019] Can't initialize character set UTF-8 (path: /usr/share/mysql/charsets/)

Comment: well then you should debug it like :
$db = new PDO(
        "mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;",
        $db_user,
        $db_pass
    );
remove charset=UTF-8 at the time of connecting.

Comment: is it just a matter or removing the -8 and making it utf8

Comment: haha, the UTF-8 instead of utf8 was causing the problem.  I knew it was something tiny that I missed.  Thanks for all the help Govind.

Comment: use this to set char set.

$db->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

Answer (score 25):

you simple change UTF-8  to utf8..

```
try {
      $db = new PDO(
              "mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;charset=utf8",
              $db_user,
              $db_pass
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

Has it worked before ? I guess your problem is that "localhost" needs to be "127.0.0.1" or similar.

Comment: I changed all that info so I could post it here, but I had the correct info in there.  No it hasn't worked before

Answer (score 0):

$db->query(...) is for SELECT and you are setting a param.

Try

$db->exec(...) instead and that could solve.

Comment: also perhaps get rid of tick marks on utf8 so just:  $pdo->query("SET NAMES utf8");  I guess depends on what you need to return (query vs. exec) but likely exec is best and just number of rows affected in return.

Comment: Note others have had issues with this:  https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47224  but you are not using the attribute so should work.